# combining 2 reducers ngrx angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

i have kinda big issue in my project, working with angular 2 (changeDetection onPush) & ngrx, my project has 3 dumb components and one smart component that managing them, its looks something like this:

[Sorry for the UX, im not a designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp4ul.jpg)

So i have 1 reducer for the Tags and the other one for the items, the lists has the same type of item its just depends if the item is finished or not to be included of each list.

Until now sounds good, but my problem is that the Tags can filter cross over the application and the lists filter of the search box effects just on the self list and the map, on the ngOnChanges of the lists im execute the search filter and emit to the smart component the filtered items, and the smart component dispatch to store to change the "isFiltered" property.

**Where's my problem is ?**
I cant manage both of the filters, 'cause i added "isFiltered" property on the type of item, but its effects different for the filters, i mean i have a combineLatest that managing the filter of items looks something like that:

```
Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
  items,
  tags,
  (items, tags) => {
    return items.map((item) => {
      item.isFiltered = item.isFiltered && tags.includes(item.tagId);
      return item;
  })
})
```

its not working well, and its kinda problem cause its a routine that the refernce to the observable changed the ngOnChange jumps and calling the dispatch again, tryed alot of things, at first i added the UPDATE_TAGS action in the items reducer and handle it there, but i read that its not the best practice to listen to the same action in 2 reducers.
After that i tryed to handle it in the same reducer but i cant know which items filtered from the tags and which from the search box.

The only way i thought about and it will work is another property on the item of isFilteredTags, and isFilteredLists.

Let me know if u have an answer for me, its will help me.
Thank you.